# How to use the element of one list as a condition for another list in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with elements = B.Tech. , M.Tech. , B.Sc. etc.
If user chooses B.Tech. then the list of departments must open in another list.

But I don't know how to do this using html and js.

I am creating two lists and whatever i choose in upper list the second list opens same.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Register </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/style_css/style_register.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/logic_js/javasc.js" >
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="regForm" action="" method="get"><br><br>
        <table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=10 nowrap>
                <tr><td><label for="a_1"> Name </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="a_1" id="a_1" ></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="a_2"> E-mail Id</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="a_2" id="a_2"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="a_3"> Mobile No. </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="a_3" id="a_3"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="a_4"> Course </label></td>
                <td><select name="a_5" id="a_5">
                    <option>B.Tech.</option>
                    <option>B.Sc.</option>
                    <option>B.Com.</option>
                    <option>B.Pharm.</option>
                    <option>M.Tech.</option>
                    <option>M.Sc.</option>
                    <option>M.Com.</option>
                    <option>M.Pharm.</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="a_6"> Department </label></td>
                <td><script type="text/javascript">
                    function getCourse(form)
                    {
                        var chCourse=form.a_5.value;
                        if(chCourse=="B.tech")
                        {
                            </script>
                            <select name="a_6"  id="a_6" >
                                <option>C.S.E.</option>
                                <option>I.T.</option>
                                <option>M.E.</option>
                                <option>C.E.</option>
                                <option>E.E.</option>
                            </select>
                            <script>
                        }
                    }   
                    </script></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Pick" onClick="getResult(this.form)"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't end a `<script>` in the middle of a function like that. This isn't PHP, you don't go out of script mode to produce literal text.

Comment: check this http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Chained-Selects-Chained.html and http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Chained-Selects-Chained/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has plugin to achieve this. Its pretty straight forward.

LINK: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

In your HTML use 2 select boxes.

```
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="BTech">B Tech</option>
  <option value="MTech">M Tech</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="BTech Option 1" class="BTech">BTech Option 1</option>
  <option value="BTech Option 2" class="BTech">BTech Option 2</option>
  <option value="BTech Option 3" class="BTech">BTech Option 3</option>
  <option value="MTech Option 1" class="MTech">MTech Option 1</option>
  <option value="MTech Option 2" class="MTech">MTech Option 2</option>
  <option value="MTech Option 3" class="MTech">MTech Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Call the load script in DOM Ready

```
$("#series").chained("#mark"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); */
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/xmx3vh5f/

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange property of the select box. For eg:

```
<select onchange="updateList()"> <option> OPtion1 </option>
         <option> OPtion2 </option>
         <option> OPtion3 </option>
<select> 

<select id="mysecondList"></select>

<script> 
     function updateList(event) {
         if( event.srcElement.value === "B.Tech") {
             //Add to your second list
             document.getElementById("mysecondList").appendChild();
         }
         .............
     }
</script>
```